# Parsing XML with line breaks / newline characters with Perl's LibXML

Tags: xml, perl, libxml2

I'm trying to parse a series of XML files with Perl's [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML) module.

```
<log date="2012-08-07 18:05:44.0" level="unit" label="2G-or-3G-server" name="unitnote" value="# Firmware level after downgrade
#
-&amp;gt; show /HOST

 /HOST
    Targets:
        bootmode
        diag
        domain ...."
```

Where some of the values contain output from the execution of scripts.   When I try to parse these values, I end up with something like the following:

```
my $value  = $log->findvalue('@value');
print "value: $value\n";
```

Output:

```
# Firmware level after downgrade    #   -&amp;gt; show /HOST  /HOST  Targets:      bootmode        diag        domain ....
```

I can't seem to find any way to have LibXML respect newlines.  Any idea?

Comment: Isn't it simply conforming to the XML specification? See http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#AVNormalize. If you want the attribute's value, after normalization, to include newlines, you need to use `&#xA;` rather than a literal newline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [XML 1.0 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#AVNormalize) says that any whitespace characters in attribute values (space, CR, LF, tab) must be converted to a space before processing

Unfortunately any properly-working XML processor will give you the same problem

This is very odd XML. Where did it come from? The `value` attribute should really be presented as PCDATA so that it can be processed properly. Is there any way you can change the data you are getting?

If there is any way you could preprocess the data so that your newlines are replaced with character references `&#xA;` then they will be translated to LF characters when the data is processed. This really should be done by whatever is generating the XML

Comment: The data came from a previous 'engineer' who stored results of input boxes in xml files.

I think processing the XML file before I attempt to insert the data into my database and and changing newline characters to &#xA; is the way to go.   

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The [Attribute-Value Normalization](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#AVNormalize) section of the [XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/) *requires* the behaviour exhibited by [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aLibXML).

> For a white space character (#x20, #xD, #xA, #x9), append a space character (#x20) to the normalized value.

There is no [documented](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aLibXML%3a%3aParser) option to change this behaviour.

If the attribute value is suppose to contain a newline, `&#x0A;` or similar has to be used instead of an actual newline.