# Replace strings only within a regex match in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have an XML document with text in attribute values. I can't change how the the XML file is generated, but need to extract the attribute values without loosing \r\n. The XML parser of course strips them out.

So I'm trying to replace \r\n in attribute values with entity references 
 I'm using perl to do this because of it's non-greedy matching. But I need help getting the replace to happen only within the match.  Or I need an easier way to do this :)

Here's is what I have so far:

```
perl -i -pe 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s/m_description="(.*?)"/m_description="$1"/smg' tmp.xml
```

This matches what I need to work with: (.*?). But I don't know to expand that pattern to match \r\n inside it, and do the replacement in the results. If I knew how many \r\n I have I could do it, but it seems I need a variable number of capture groups or something like that? There's a lot to regex I don't understand and it seems like there should be something do do this.

Example:

```
preceding lines 
stuff m_description="Over
any number
of lines" other stuff
more lines
```

Should go to:

```
preceding lines 
stuff m_description="Over&#13;&#10;any number&#13;&#10;of lines" other stuff
more lines
```

**Solution**

Thanks to Ikegam and ysth for the solution I used, which for 5.14+ is:

```
perl -i -0777 -pe's/m_description="\K(.*?)(?=")/ $1 =~ s!\n!&#10;!gr =~ s!\r!&#13;!gr /sge' tmp.xml
```

Comment: show sample data?  what you show isn't XML

Comment: You probably want something like that `perl -i -p0e 's/m_description="\K([^"]*)/$1=~s%\r\n%&#13;&#10;%gr/ge'` (`-0` is roughly the same as `BEGIN{undef $/}`).

Comment: I think you need a rolled up copy of the XML spec to prod people with. Almost like XML, but not quite is pretty filthy. A perl one liner will be hard to read. Writing it as a script in which you extract and reformat the description would be easier.

Comment: Get an XML parser. Using a regex for XML is just ugly.

Comment: @Robert, They [can't](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12099614/589924). The XML was incorrectly built, and they are trying to fix it so that an XML parser can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` should already match `\n` (because you specify the `/s` flag) and `\r`.

To do the replacement in the results, use `/e`:

```
perl -i -0777 -pe's/(?<=m_description=")(.*?)(?=")/ my $replacement=$1; $replacement=~s!\n!&#10;!g; $replacement=~s!\r!&#13;!g; $replacement /sge' tmp.xml
```

I've also changed it to use lookbehind/lookahead to make the code simpler and to use -0777 to set `$/` to slurp mode and to remove the useless `/m`.

Comment: `m_description="\K` is more efficient and less noisy than `(?<=m_description=")`. Requires 5.10+

Comment: `my $replacement=$1; $replacement=~s!\n!&#10;!g; $replacement=~s!\r!&#13;!g; $replacement` can also be written as `$1 =~ s!\n!&#10;!gr =~ s!\r!&#13;!gr` if you have 5.14+

Comment: what ikegami said.  I was just too lazy to look up those two required perl versions.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so whilst this looks like an XML problem, it isn't. The XML problem is the person generating it. You should probably give them a prod with a rolled up copy of the spec as your first port of call for "fixing" this.

But failing that - I'd do a two pass approach, where I read the text, find all the 'blobs' that match a description, and then replace them all.

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $text = do { local $/ ;  <DATA> }; 

#filter text for 'description' text: 
my @matches = $text =~ m{m_description=\"([^\"]+)\"}gms;

print Dumper \@matches; 

#Generate a search-and-replace hash
my %replace = map { $_ => s/[\r\n]+/&#13;&#10;/gr } @matches; 
print Dumper \%replace;

#turn the keys of that hash into a search regex
my $search = join ( "|", keys %replace ); 
   $search = qr/\"($search)\"/ms; 

print "Using search regex: $search\n";
#search and replace text block
$text =~ s/m_description=$search/m_description="$replace{$1}"/mgs;

print "New text:\n";
print $text;

__DATA__
preceding lines 
stuff m_description="Over
any number
of lines" other stuff
more lines
```